# Application's view differs in ios 5 compared to ios 4

Tags: ipad, uiviewcontroller, ios5, uiinterfaceorientation

I have developed a ebook reder which supports ios 3.2 and above versions of ipad.The ebook reader shows a single page in portrait mode and 2 pages in landscape mode. The application works fine on ios 4.3.

I tried the same application on another device which runs on ios 5, the application works fine until i change the orientation.Once the orientation is changed the view sizes are not proper and it seems like it is taking portrait view size in landscape and vice versa.

what is the difference with ios 4 and ios 5 regarding orientation changes ,etc.

I searched on internet but could not find the exact reason or solution.One of the stack overflow search was describing the container view concept in ios 5, but it is not sufficient for me.

Can someone help me in resolving my issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how helpful this is but it has caused some troubles for me.  iOS5 has improved the forwarding of messages to child views and viewControllers.  Things like viewDidAppear, viewDidDissappear, rotation notices, etc.  The problem is that since these were not reliably forwarded in earlier versions things you may have done to compensate for that short coming may mean that now those functions are getting called twice.  Not sure if that's your issue but it could be.